# How can I display the SubTotal on OpenCart on any page?

Tags: php, str-replace, opencart, substr

Currently the only global PHP command I know is:

```
<?=$text_items?>
```

This spits:

```
1 item(s) - £318.75
```

I want to get the `318.75` value so at the moment I am trying a replace but it is not working all smoothly:

```
$short = $text_items;
$short = str_replace("£", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("&pound;", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("-", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("&ndash;", "", $short);
$short = str_replace(" ", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("-", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("ITEMS", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("(", "", $short);
$short = str_replace(")", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("item(s)", "", $short);
$short = str_replace("ITEM", "", $short);
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the variable directly instead of having to parse it through the text like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$total = @floatval(end(explode('£', html_entity_decode($text_items))));
```

- `html_entity_decode` changes `&pound;` to `£`
- `end(explode('£'` is giving you string after '`£`' character
- finally `floatval` is valuating string to float.
- @ is bypassing `E_STRICT` error which occurs to passing constant in `end()` function.

[Working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/anfiTK)

---

Second solution is Regexp:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $text_items, $result);
echo $result[1];
```

[Working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xciqPQ)

Comment: I only want the value `318.75` no pound signs, no dashes. Just that value. Basically the value after the £ GBP sign.

Comment: yeah so i gave you two solutions. Did you even check on my examples?

Comment: Thanks. What is fast and better to use? Could you also explain the Regex.

Comment: I recommend you 1st solution. Regex is simply looking for two decimals and dot `.` in string